# cant install grub after removing windows

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning

I had windows 10 installed on my laptop. and I've uninstalled it yesterday.
the problem is i have also formatted the sda1 partition to fresh install grub on it.
but when i try ubuntu repair tool it fails and gives the following summary.

http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/cwQ5GBvdrB/

when i try to reboot i get the grub2 command line not booting to ubuntu directly.

[image: partition table]

Comment: Is the image from before the sda1 formatting or taken using liveUSB Gparted or similar rescue usb?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are at least 2 ways of solving this issue:

### 1.Using grub command line directly

Grub and grub-rescue uses a command line syntax that may be a little off putting and cumbersome at first, but it is a good idea to know at least the basics for critical situations like this one:

- First, set the paging for long commands

`grub>set pager=1`

- Next, list the available volumes/partitions

`grub>ls`

- As your output, you will get something similar to:

  `(hd0) (hd0,msdos1) (hd0,msdos2) (hd0, msdos3)`
- Every one of these msdos[1-3] partitions can then be checked with `ls` and eventually one of them will match the directory structure of your linux OS.

  ```
  grub>ls (hd0,2)
  bin/ boot/ cdrom/ dev/ etc/ home/  lib/ lib64/ media/ mnt/ opt/ proc/ root/ run/ sbin/ srv/ sys/ tmp/ usr/ var/ initrd.img initrd.img.old vmlinuz vmlinuz.old
  ```
- Once you find your linux partition you have to set the prefix and then set the partition as root.

  ```
  grub>set prefix=(hd0,2)/boot/grub
  grub>set root=set root=(hd0,2)
  ```
- then the `linux` and `initrd` commands, the root=/dev/sdaX should be changed accordingly with X being your partition number, here I am using 2 as an example. The [version] will correspond to your kernel version. If you have `vmlinuz` and `initrd` symlinked from `/vmlinuz` and `/initrd.img` then you can just use those as the path for simplicity.

  ```
  grub>linux /boot/vmlinuz-[version] root=/dev/sda2
  grub>initrd /boot/initrd.img-[version]
  grub>boot
  ```
- This will get you into your linux OS, once there proceed with rebuilding the grub

### 2.Using live rescue disk like GParted.

Once booted up, you should have access to a terminal capable of rebuilding and installing the corrected grub to your hard drive using the below commands.

### Updating and installing the correct grub

- from terminal, execute:

`$sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg`

or

`$sudo update-grub`

- and then install the grub to the hard drive (not individual partition), here I am again using /dev/sda as an example.

`$sudo grub-install /dev/sda`

And that is all there is to it. These commands have been repeated dozens of times on StackExchange, but I find it a good idea to simply rewrite them when someone asks, because it is one of those things I don't ever want to forget.

Comment: first one worked fine. thank you